# Group list-items into sub-lists based on a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append the `<li>` from one `<ul>` to another `<ul>` that's created on the fly. I want to group the list-items into new sub-lists based on their `data-group` attribute.

```
<ul id="sortable1">
    <li data-group="A">test</li>
    <li data-group="A">test1</li>
    <li data-group="B">test2</li>
    <li data-group="B">test3</li>
    <li data-group="C">test4</li>
</ul>
```

Basically I'm trying to loop through this list and grap all `<li>` from each group, and then move it to another `<ul>`.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not getting the expected results. I have done this in Excel in the past but can't get it to work with jQuery.

```
var listItems = $("#sortable1").children("li");
listItems.each(function (idx, li) {
    var product = $(li);
    //grab current li
    var str = $(this).text();

    if (idx > 0) {
        //append li
        str += str;
        if ($(this).data("group") != $(this).prev().data("group")) {
            //I should be getting  test and test1. 
            //but alert is only giving test1 test1. 

            alert(str);
            //need to break into groups
            //do something with groups
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you simply want to copy the inner `li` elements into the other `ul` ? Or you want to **move** them?

Comment: Do you want to move multiple groups simultaneously, or just one at a time? If the latter, then select only the elements in that group in the first place, using the the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, Ideally I want to move them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```js
$(function() {
    var sortable = $("#sortable1"),
        content = $("#content");

    var groups = [];
    sortable.find("li").each(function() { 
        var group = $(this).data("group");
        if($.inArray(group, groups) === -1) {
            groups.push(group);
        }
    });
    
    groups.forEach(function(group) { 
        var liElements = sortable.find("li[data-group='" + group + "']"),
            groupUl = $("<ul>").append(liElements);
        content.append(groupUl);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable1">
    <li data-group="A">test</li>
    <li data-group="A">test1</li>
    <li data-group="B">test2</li>
    <li data-group="B">test3</li>
    <li data-group="C">test4</li>
</ul>

<div id="content">    
</div>
```

I hope I didn't misunderstand you.

Comment: What if the groups are more than `A`, `B`, `C`? I think it's good idea to generate that array dynamically.

Comment: I marked as an answer because this will work but @ROX is correct that I was looking for a more dynamic way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: @causita I'm glad I could help. I've done a little edit that generates the array of groups dynamically.